# Select oracle schema which only contains specific table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I'm looking for a way to select all schema on my oracle server, which only contain the table "mytable"

How can i do this ?

I already have a query who list all schema in my database.

```
SELECT username FROM all_users;
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look this up on the [`all_tables`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm) system table:

```
select distinct owner
from all_tables
where table_name = 'mytable'
```

Comment: +1 Adrian - you beat me to it by seconds :) Also note @Adeel that this will only show tables you've been granted access to, so results may vary depending on the user who executes the query. That's not a problem with the query; it's just how Oracle works.